# How to merge into my git?

Tags: git, github

I want to [**merge**](http://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base)

branch `jb-mr1-release`

my git branch is `jellybean`

How to merge from Android googlesource into `jellybean`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this

```
git remote add upstream https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base
git checkout jellybean
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/jb-mr1-release
```

[**ref**](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/master/scripts/git-merge.sh)